# Margin-right not working with right floated element in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div called `chat-sample` with two elements, one floated to the left and the other to the right:

```
<div class='chat-sample'><p class='text-muted pull-left'>Did you know that there are only really 3 continets on earth? Please reply with interest for an explanation.</p><div class='delete pull-right'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></div></div>
```

I am trying the `margin-right` property on the paragraph (when there is a long message) so that the trash icon doesn't move to a new line but it doesn't work.

```
.chat-sample p {
    margin-right: 120px;
}
```

I would like the trash icon in the same position as the other messages from Boss and John Appleseed.

```css
.glyphicon-user {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #3399ff;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.panel-heading {
 position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: -moz-sticky;
   position: -ms-sticky;
   position: -o-sticky;
   position: sticky;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 99999;
 top: 0;
}

.panel-heading h1 {
 padding-bottom: 0.65em;
 color: #3399ff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.panel-body {
 padding: 0;
}

.col-xs-12 {
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}

.chats {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.chats li {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}

.chats a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 85px;
 padding: 15px 0;
}

.chats a:hover,
.chats a:hover .glyphicon-user,
.chats a:hover .text-muted {
 background-color: #3399ff;
 color: white;
}

.chats .sender {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.chats .timestamp {
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.chats .chat-sample {
 clear: right;
 margin-left: 50px;
 padding-top: 5px;
}

.chat-sample p {
 margin-right: 120px;
}

.chats .delete {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.chats li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-centered'>
    <div class='panel panel-default'>
     <div class='panel-heading sticky'>
      <div class='btn-group pull-left'>
       <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'</span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
         <li><a href='#'>Delete All Chats</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
       <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>
         <li><a href='#'>New Chat</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <h1 class='panel-title text-center'>FunChat</h1>
     </div>
     <div class='panel-body'>
      <ul class='chats'>
       <li>
        <a href='#'>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>John Appleseed</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> 08/12/2016</small></div>
         <div class='chat-sample'><p class='text-muted pull-left'>What time is it?</p><div class='delete pull-right'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></div></div>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href='#'>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Teacher</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> 08/12/2016</small></div>
         <div class='chat-sample'><p class='text-muted pull-left'>Did you know that there are only really 3 continets on earth? Please reply with interest for an explanation.</p><div class='delete pull-right'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></div></div>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href='#'>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Boss</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> 08/12/2016</small></div>
         <div class='chat-sample'><p class='text-muted pull-left'>Why aren't you at work?</p><div class='delete pull-right'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></div></div>
        </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><!--end column-->
  </div><!--end row 1-->
</div><!--end container-->
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a jsfiddle link that has some improved CSS, please check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following change in the css:

```
.chat-sample p {
   /* margin-right: 120px; */
   width: 80%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I guess what I forgot was the width

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid this kind of issue, instead of a `margin-right`, you can apply a fixed `width` to the `<p>` element.

```
.chat-sample p {
  width: <yourPreferedSize> px/%;
}
```

If you have a fixed size for it and want to have it responsive ready, make sure you update the `width` for every screen size.

**UPDATED:**

A piece of advice: Try to avoid fixed heights on elements, for example `<a>` in your code. When you have fixed width on child elements (`<p>` in your example) and fixed height of parent element (`<a>`) if the content in the `<p>` is really long, the design will break.

You have [here](https://jsfiddle.net/93yvg7x5/) the updated CSS with the fix.

Comment: Thanks. The fixed height I will solve with JavaScript to cut off the text at a certain length so no worries. The same way all your text messages have fixed height